# JQuery TableSorter click actions have no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I must be doing something stupidly wrong, but I'm not seeing it. On my site, I attach the JQuery TableSorter to a table and hope to have some sorting done, but clicks have no effect. No sorting happens. It just remains as a static table.

Here's a simplified JSFiddle of the problem I'm having:

http://jsfiddle.net/96AEE/3/

It's a very simple table with javascript as follows:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tablesorter" id="gift_certificates">
    <thead>
        <tr class="nav">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll();" class="short" value="1" id="check_all" name="check_all" />
            </td>
            <td>Gift Cert</td>
            <td>Note</td>
            <td>Order #</td>
            <td>Order Date</td>
            <td>Amount</td>
            <td>Redeemed</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"></td>
            <td>ss1q</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>$300.00</td>
            <td>    <a href="test.php">Sale</a>

            </td>
            <td>true</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="checkbox" value="103" onclick="document.getElementById('check_all').checked = false;" class="short" id="check_103" name="check_103" />
            </td>
            <td>443ss</td>
            <td>(1d10t) Arizona Tea</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>$50.00</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="checkbox" value="50" onclick="document.getElementById('check_all').checked = false;" class="short" id="check_50" name="check_50" />
            </td>
            <td>199e</td>
            <td>(#9000) Over</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>$300.00</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="checkbox" value="87" onclick="document.getElementById('check_all').checked = false;" class="short" id="check_87" name="check_87" />
            </td>
            <td>F990</td>
            <td>($09aa) Trouble</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>$300.00</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tablesorter").tablesorter();
});
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: In case you're interested, I have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) with lots of enhancements... and it also allows `td`'s within the table head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to your markup on the HTML table.

Within the thead element, you need to use th tags instead of td.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        ...
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Working JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bybFK/

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your header row to use `<th>` tags instead of `<td>`  tags.

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely neglecting something, when creating the header of your table; your are using `<td>` instead of using `<th>`
you also do not need to assign the class `tablesorter to your table`

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tablesorter" id="gift_certificates">
    <thead>
        <tr class="nav">
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll();" class="short" value="1" id="check_all" name="check_all" />
            </th>
            <th>Gift Cert</th>
            <th>Note</th>
            <th>Order #</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Redeemed</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"></td>
            <td>ss1q</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>$300.00</td>
            <td>    <a href="test.php">Sale</a>

            </td>
            <td>true</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="checkbox" value="87" onclick="document.getElementById('check_all').checked = false;" class="short" id="check_87" name="check_87" />
            </td>
            <td>F990</td>
            <td>($09aa) Trouble</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>$300.00</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#gift_certificates").tablesorter();
    });
```

http://tablesorter.com/docs/